# How to combine workbooks from their actual start values (no appending)

Tags: vba, excel

I’m really sorry if this is a silly question but the macro I’m currently using keeps appending the new workbooks data when I’m combining them.

Ideally, I want the new workbook to be beside it at cells AA1 instead of directly appending like it is in the picture.  I’m sorry I can’t be much more help.  I’ve been going through it trying to get it to start for the other workbooks to not append but write where it actually is from the other workbooks.  No luck so far.

I’m sure I’ll get there in a few hours or so, but thanks again if you’re willing to assist.
[image]

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CombineManyWorkbooksIntoOneWorksheet()

    Dim strDirContainingFiles As String, strFile As String, _
        strFilePath As String
    Dim wbkDst As Workbook, wbkSrc As Workbook
    Dim wksDst As Worksheet, wksSrc As Worksheet
    Dim lngIdx As Long, lngSrcLastRow As Long, _
        lngSrcLastCol As Long, lngDstLastRow As Long, _
        lngDstLastCol As Long, lngDstFirstFileRow As Long
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDst As Range, rngFile As Range
    Dim colFileNames As Collection
    Set colFileNames = New Collection

    'Set references up-front
    strDirContainingFiles = "C:\Users\Guide\Projects\" '<~ your folder
    Set wbkDst = Workbooks.Add '<~ Dst is short for destination
    Set wksDst = wbkDst.ActiveSheet

    'Store all of the file names in a collection
    strFile = Dir(strDirContainingFiles & "\*.xlsm")
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        colFileNames.Add Item:=strFile
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    ''CHECKPOINT: make sure colFileNames has the file names
    'Dim varDebug As Variant
    'For Each varDebug In colFileNames
    '    Debug.Print varDebug
    'Next varDebug

    'Now we can start looping through the "source" files
    'and copy their data to our destination sheet
    For lngIdx = 1 To colFileNames.Count

        'Assign the file path
        strFilePath = strDirContainingFiles & "\" & colFileNames(lngIdx)

        'Open the workbook and store a reference to the data sheet
        Set wbkSrc = Workbooks.Open(strFilePath)
        Set wksSrc = wbkSrc.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Identify the last row and last column, then
        'use that info to identify the full data range
        lngSrcLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)
        lngSrcLastCol = LastOccupiedColNum(wksSrc)
        With wksSrc
            Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngSrcLastRow, _
                                                     lngSrcLastCol))
        End With

        ''CHECKPOINT: make sure we have the full source data range
        'wksSrc.Range("A1").Select
        'rngSrc.Select

        'If this is the first (1st) loop, we want to keep
        'the header row from the source data, but if not then
        'we want to remove it
        If lngIdx <> 1 Then
            Set rngSrc = rngSrc.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngSrc.Rows.Count - 1)
        End If

        ''CHECKPOINT: make sure that we remove the header row
        ''from the source range on every loop that is not
        ''the first one
        'wksSrc.Range("A1").Select
        'rngSrc.Select

        'Copy the source data to the destination sheet, aiming
        'for cell A1 on the first loop then one past the
        'last-occupied row in column A on each following loop
        If lngIdx = 1 Then
            lngDstLastRow = 1
            Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(1, 1)
        Else
            lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)
            Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)
        End If
        rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst '<~ this is the copy / paste

        'Almost done! We want to add the source file info
        'for each of the data blocks to our destination

        'On the first loop, we need to add a "Source Filename" column
        If lngIdx = 1 Then
            lngDstLastCol = LastOccupiedColNum(wksDst)
            wksDst.Cells(1, lngDstLastCol + 1) = "Source Filename"
        End If

        'Identify the range that we need to write the source file
        'info to, then write the info
        With wksDst

            'The first row we need to write the file info to
            'is the same row where we did our initial paste to
            'the destination file
            lngDstFirstFileRow = lngDstLastRow + 1

            'Then, we need to find the NEW last row on the destination
            'sheet, which will be further down (since we pasted more
            'data in)
            lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)
            lngDstLastCol = LastOccupiedColNum(wksDst)

            'With the info from above, we can create the range
            Set rngFile = .Range(.Cells(lngDstFirstFileRow, lngDstLastCol), _
                                 .Cells(lngDstLastRow, lngDstLastCol))

            ''CHECKPOINT: make sure we have correctly identified
            ''the range where our file names will go
            'wksDst.Range("A1").Select
            'rngFile.Select

            'Now that we have that range identified,
            'we write the file name
            rngFile.Value = wbkSrc.Name

        End With

        'Close the source workbook and repeat
        wbkSrc.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Next lngIdx

    'Let the user know that the combination is done!
    ''MsgBox "Data combined!"

End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last row
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied row
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
Public Function LastOccupiedRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim lng As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        With Sheet
            lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Row
        End With
    Else
        lng = 1
    End If
    LastOccupiedRowNum = lng
End Function

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last column
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied column
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
Public Function LastOccupiedColNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim lng As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        With Sheet
            lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Column
        End With
    Else
        lng = 1
    End If
    LastOccupiedColNum = lng
End Function
```

Comment: I am able to rotate the data around but it seems appending is pretty ingrained into this.  Lots of errors popup when I want to change whats causing this..

Comment: I'll keep on trying.  It's not the end of the world if this doesn't work, though the other method requires another 8 steps.. and launching and reopening excels (not good for cpu but unavoidable if unable to get this going)

Comment: just to clarify, the data range in picture (top left corner at AP173) should be  at AA1 ( or some column offset from A1) ???

Comment: @jsotola Correct.  The data at Ap173 in the original workbook is at AA1 but the macro keeps appending it after the other workbooks data

Comment: i skimmed your code. you are calculating the bottom right corner of previous data. then you append new data at that point. just calculate last column, and make row = 1 for new data

Comment: was previous data filling columns up to **AO** ?

Comment: @jsotola Well both workbooks start at at Cell 1 but different columns and wanting to merge.  Though this keeps appending it which defeats the purpose of it I guess.  I have been using standard copy and paste but its not ideal when you have limited CPU.   Hmm could you specify where abouts specifically or give an example to change?  I can't seem to be able to get that to work unfortunately and not for lack of trying

Comment: you did not write this code then

Comment: @jsotola It's above my knowledge yes.  I concede that if I am unable to get it to work, then I will stick with what I know certainly.

Comment: please describe in detail what you want the program to do. (not how you want to fix this one, but how it should behave when it works correctly). include all details about reading files, if any... columns and rows used .... and so on  .... please add the description into your question.

Comment: please replace the picture in your question if you can. show column A,  and make column **L** to **AO** very narrow so we can still see column **AU**. ...  maybe post another picture that shows top  rows ( is there anything in columns **L** to **AO**  ?)

Comment: @jsotola I'll post the working code as my answer.  I fiddled around with it a bit more and slowly debugged it deleting stuff that did not appear to fix it.  Not sure if this new code is advisable or will break in the future but it worked for me

Comment: glad you figured it out. i had a closer look at the original. i think it did this: ... get a list of files in C:\Users\Guide\Projects\ ... open each of those files and append the content to a master worksheet, starting at next free row and starting in column A  ... also append a column on right side of the just pasted data and fill it with the Source Filename

Comment: @jsotola Yeah it does exactly as you described.  My solution works provided that you keep the wksDst.Cells(1, 20) y value above a certain point otherwise it tends to automatically append.  Not really a true fix, but provided you keep both data separate by a large degree shouldn't be an issue.  Guess time will tell.

Comment: in your picture. the data from file _data.xlsm_ is pasted in range A173:AT212.  the filename is appended in range AU173:AU212

Comment: the problem with the original program is that the data should have been imported starting at column B, and the source filename should be in column A, because the data in the different workbooks does not have same number of columns ( example: pokemon.xlsm uses columns **A** to **I** and data.xlsm uses columns **A** to **AT**  )

Comment: @jsotola In which case I just got both workbooks, and put all the column data starting at Cell A.  Then I can change that y value for whatever column I want it in.  This tends to work better.  There should be no fear of overlapping because unless you want to overwrite the data that would be pointless so I believe this solution works well :D

Comment: @jsotola Probably not a true fix but I mean its working now I guess so I can't complain xD

Comment: how many files are you appending?  i still would be interested in what columns A to J look like if you don't mind (replace any private info with garbage data)

Comment: @jsotola Generally this is working fine for 2 files.  However I added a new file and it seems to automatically make sure that it does not override other data. Thats quite interesting.  I think if you wanted to specific whereabouts you'd have to modify existing code to create a y value for this third input I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should identify the individual tasks that you program will have to perform and create methods and functions to handle these smaller tasks.  Doing this will allow you to easily debug your code.

- get1stCellInNextColumn - Defines the Target range
- getFileCollection - Collect all the file paths
- getLastUsedCell - Gets the last used cell in a range.  Used to define both Source and Target ranges
- getSourceRange - Gets the Source Range
- InsertData - Opens a Source file and copies its data to a Target Workbook
- Main_CombineManyWorkbooksIntoOneWorksheet - Process all the files

---

```
Option Explicit

'This is the Main function that combines all the other Subs and Functions together to process the data

Public Sub Main_CombineManyWorkbooksIntoOneWorksheet()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Const FOLDERNAME As String = "C:\Users\best buy\Downloads\_Temp\" ' "C:\Users\Guide\"
    Const EXTENSION As String = "\*.xlsx" '"\*.xlsm"
    Dim cFiles As Collection
    Dim x As Long

    Set cFiles = getFileCollection(FOLDERNAME, EXTENSION)

    With Workbooks.Add

        For x = 1 To cFiles.Count
            InsertData cFiles.Item(x), .Worksheets(1)
        Next

    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'Opens Source Workbook, Copies Data to Target Worksheet and then closes the Source Workbook
Public Sub InsertData(SourceWBName As String, TargetWS As Worksheet)
    Dim rSource As Range

    With Workbooks.Open(SourceWBName)
        Set rSource = getSourceRange(.Worksheets("Sheet1"))
        If rSource Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print .FullName, "No Data Found"
        Else
            rSource.Copy get1stCellInNextColumn(TargetWS.UsedRange)
        End If

        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
End Sub

'Collects the full file paths for the Source workbooks
Function getFileCollection(FOLDERNAME As String, FileExtension As String) As Collection
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim col As Collection
    Set col = New Collection
    'Store all of the file names in a collection
    FileName = Dir(FOLDERNAME & FileExtension)
    Do While Len(FileName) > 0
        col.Add Item:=FOLDERNAME & FileName
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    Set getFileCollection = col
End Function

'Gets the Source range from a Worksheet
Function getSourceRange(xlWS As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim rLastCell As Range
    With xlWS
        Set rLastCell = getLastUsedCell(.UsedRange, True, True)

        If Not rLastCell Is Nothing Then Set getSourceRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), rLastCell)

    End With
End Function

'Gets the first cell in the next unused Column of the Target range
Function get1stCellInNextColumn(Target As Range) As Range
    Dim r As Range
    'Get last used cell in last used column of the Target range
    Set r = getLastUsedCell(Target, False, True)

    If r Is Nothing Then
        Set r = Target.EntireColumn.Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        'Get the first cell in the next column adjacent to the Target range
        Set r = Target.Columns(Target.Columns.Count).Next
    End If

    Set get1stCellInNextColumn = r
End Function

'Gets the last used cell the last used row
'Or the last used cell the last used column
'Or the last used cells in the Target range

Function getLastUsedCell(Target As Range, InRow As Boolean, InColumn As Boolean) As Range
    Dim rRow As Range, rColumn As Range
    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    With Target

        Set rRow = .Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

        If rRow Is Nothing Then Exit Function

        Set rColumn = .Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

        If InRow And InColumn Then                    'Get last used cell in last used column
            Set getLastUsedCell = Intersect(rRow.EntireRow, rColumn.EntireColumn)
        ElseIf InRow Then                             'Get last used cell in last used row
            Set getLastUsedCell = rRow
        ElseIf InColumn Then                          'Get last used cell in last used column
            Set getLastUsedCell = rColumn
        End If

    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks looks good.  Is there a way to specificity where each workbook goes in the new workbook.  Say you had 3 workbooks and you want to merge them at cells 1, 50 and 100.  The code I was able to manipulate allowed this for only 2 workbooks.  I suppose you could just merge them as they were originally...  I'll try that though selecting where all 3 workbooks would go would be pretty handy

Comment: The way it works now every time you call `InsertData(SourceWBName, TargetWS)` it will copy the data from the Source workbook to the first cell of next available column.  You can do this for as many workbooks as you want (until you run out of columns).

Comment: If you want to change the destination of the data then you'll have to modify `get1stCellInNextColumn`.  The advantage of setting it up this way is that you can test the functionality separately from the main program.  For example, you could modify `get1stCellInNextColumn` and then test it by typing `?get1stCellInNextColumn(ActiveWorksheet.UsedRange).Address` into the   Immediate Window and pressing enter.   This will give you the destination address of the new data.

Comment: I'd say this pretty well does the job.  My only critique is that if I have three worksheets and say I wanted to insert worksheet data 1 under worksheet data 2 it does not appear to let me do this.  Other than that though if I keep everything separate it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question but I figured it out after a bit of debugging. The following code below does not append and creates the excels exactly as you need them.  Change the values as you see fit or use original code if you need to append.

```
Option Explicit
    Public Sub CombineManyWorkbooksIntoOneWorksheet()

        Dim strDirContainingFiles As String, strFile As String, _
            strFilePath As String
        Dim wbkDst As Workbook, wbkSrc As Workbook
        Dim wksDst As Worksheet, wksSrc As Worksheet
        Dim lngIdx As Long, lngSrcLastRow As Long, _
            lngSrcLastCol As Long, lngDstLastRow As Long, _
            lngDstLastCol As Long, lngDstFirstFileRow As Long
        Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDst As Range, rngFile As Range
        Dim colFileNames As Collection
        Set colFileNames = New Collection

        'Set references up-front
        strDirContainingFiles = "C:\Users\Guide\" '<~ your folder
        Set wbkDst = Workbooks.Add '<~ Dst is short for destination
        Set wksDst = wbkDst.ActiveSheet

        'Store all of the file names in a collection
        strFile = Dir(strDirContainingFiles & "\*.xlsm")
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0
            colFileNames.Add Item:=strFile
            strFile = Dir
        Loop

        ''CHECKPOINT: make sure colFileNames has the file names
        'Dim varDebug As Variant
        'For Each varDebug In colFileNames
        '    Debug.Print varDebug
        'Next varDebug

        'Now we can start looping through the "source" files
        'and copy their data to our destination sheet
        For lngIdx = 1 To colFileNames.Count

            'Assign the file path
            strFilePath = strDirContainingFiles & "\" & colFileNames(lngIdx)

            'Open the workbook and store a reference to the data sheet
            Set wbkSrc = Workbooks.Open(strFilePath)
            Set wksSrc = wbkSrc.Worksheets("Sheet1")

            'Identify the last row and last column, then
            'use that info to identify the full data range
            lngSrcLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)
            lngSrcLastCol = LastOccupiedColNum(wksSrc)
            With wksSrc
            Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngSrcLastRow, _
                                                         lngSrcLastCol))
            End With

            ''CHECKPOINT: make sure we have the full source data range
            'wksSrc.Range("A1").Select
            'rngSrc.Select

            'If this is the first (1st) loop, we want to keep
            'the header row from the source data, but if not then
            'we want to remove it


            ''CHECKPOINT: make sure that we remove the header row
            ''from the source range on every loop that is not
            ''the first one
            'wksSrc.Range("A1").Select
            'rngSrc.Select

            'Copy the source data to the destination sheet, aiming
            'for cell A1 on the first loop then one past the
            'last-occupied row in column A on each following loop
            If lngIdx = 1 Then
                lngDstLastRow = 1
                Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(1, 1)
            Else
                lngDstLastRow = 1
                Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(1, 20)
            End If
            rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst '<~ this is the copy / paste




            'Close the source workbook and repeat
            wbkSrc.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next lngIdx

        'Let the user know that the combination is done!
        ''MsgBox "Data combined!"

    End Sub

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last row
    'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied row
    'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
    Public Function LastOccupiedRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
        Dim lng As Long
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
            With Sheet
                lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                  MatchCase:=False).Row
            End With
        Else
            lng = 1
        End If
        LastOccupiedRowNum = lng
    End Function

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last column
    'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied column
    'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
    Public Function LastOccupiedColNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
        Dim lng As Long
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
            With Sheet
                lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                  MatchCase:=False).Column
            End With
        Else
            lng = 1
        End If
        LastOccupiedColNum = lng
    End Function
```

Comment: @jsotola It only lets me accept answers after two days apparently

Comment: your code will work correctly only if you have 1 or 2 workbooks in the directory. it copies the first one into range starting at **A1**, and copies the second one and all others into range starting at **T1**.  so a third workbook will corrupt the data at range **T1**

Comment: i have a suspicion that the original program may be working correctly, but the workbooks in the C:\Users\Guide\ are corrupted, or not in correct format

Comment: @jsotola Perhaps.  I've re-tested it with two workbooks and it tends to work fine.  I am unsure how you would do this with 3 though.    Where it says                                    <~ this is the copy / paste.  Above that I believe you'd have to  add a third line or something to include that.  The first line appears to refer to y value in pokemon book and the second line is the next workbook you are referring to.  I wonder if that is always constant or if they change at random.